# How do I POST a Pojo with Jersey Client without manually convert to JSON?

Tags: java, json, client, jersey, jackson

I have a working json service which looks like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/{id}/query")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(JSON)
public ListWrapper query(@Context SecurityContext sc, @PathParam("id") Integer projectId, Query searchQuery) {
    ...
    return result
}
```

The query object looks like this and when posting a json representation of that Query object it works out nice.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Query {
    Integer id;
    String query;
    ... // Getters and Setters etc..
}
```

Now I want to fill that object from a client and use Jersey client to post that Query object to the service and get an JSONObject as a result. My understanding is that it could be done without converting it to a json object first and then posted as a String.

I have tried something like this but I think I miss something.

```
public static JSONObject query(Query searchQuery){
    String url = baseUrl + "project/"+searchQuery.getProjectId() +"/query";
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
    webResource.entity(searchQuery, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    JSONObject response = webResource.post(JSONObject.class);
    return response;
}
```

I'm using Jersey 1.12.

Any help or pointer in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your web-service produces a JSON you must handle that in your client by using an `accept()` method:

```
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(searchQuery, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
ListWrapper listWrapper = response.getEntity(ListWrapper.class);
```

Try this and give your results.

Comment: Thank you!

You got me on the right track with the ClientResponse. I had to do some additional stuff also:
`WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
    ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, searchQuery);
    ListWrapper listWrapper = response.getEntity(ListWrapper.class);
`
Now I got a JsonMappingException , but I think it's an error in the json result.

Answer (score 6):

The WebResource.entity(...) method doesn't alter your webResource instance... it creates and returns a Builder object that holds the change.  Your call to .post is typically performed from a Builder object rather than from the WebResource object.  That transition is easily obscured when all the requests are chained together.

```
public void sendExample(Example example) {
    WebResource webResource = this.client.resource(this.url);
    Builder builder = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    builder.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    builder.post(Example.class, example);
    return;
}
```

Here's the same example using chaining.  It's still using a Builder, but less obviously.

```
public void sendExample(Example example) {
    WebResource webResource = this.client.resource(this.url);
    webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      .post(Example.class, example);
    return;
}
```

Comment: I can't find `WebResource` class. Please give the import code!

Comment: If you're using the 1.x branch (the OP specified version 1.12), you can find details on WebResource here: https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.9/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html