# How to pass a custom object in REST webservice

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey, jersey-client

i'm having problems transfering a custom object to the client. How can i transfer a custom object to the client and receive it back to the webservice? i'm transferring a file by chunks. i want to know how i should write my client. i tried passing it as `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` in client but i get no result meaning it doesn't get passed back to the webservice. Below is a bit of code im working on.

**Webservice**

```
 @POST
    @Path("/fileTransfer")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public final TransferInfomation transferInfo(final FileModel file)
{
...
}
```

...(some code)(lets just say a *syso*)

**FileModel Class**

```
public class FileModel {

private String fileID;
private DataHandler dataHandler;

/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public FileModel() {
}
```

(lets assume setters and getters are made)

(Not sure if the webservice is correct). Still learning REST, i want to know how the client should be.

Answer (score 3):

A good way to "marshal" and "unmarshal" "custom objects" (in JSON, XML, etc.) in Jersey is to use JAXB (https://jaxb.java.net/).

To do this you need to create a "jaxb class", with the proper getters and setters (and annotations), e.g.:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class FileModel{

    private String fileID;
    private DataHandler dataHandler;

    public String getFileID(){
        return fileID;
    }

    public void setFileID(String fileID){
        this.fileID = fileID;
    }

    public DataHandler getDataHandler(){
        return dataHandler;
    }

    public void setDataHandler(DataHandler dataHandler){
        this.dataHandler = dataHandler;
    }

}
```

Do not forget to declare the `@XmlRootElement`. Then you can simply declare and use these objects in your API endpoints (methods):

```
@POST
@Path("/fileTransfer")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public final FileModel transferInfo(FileModel file)
{
    // read file in "FileModel" format
    // ... make several operations
    // return new FileModel (or another format if you will)
}
```

This should work. Make sure you follow the data structure defined for FileModel correctly in the client side. See here a example on how to handle that in Jersey: [How do I POST a Pojo with Jersey Client without manually convert to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335483/how-do-i-post-a-pojo-with-jersey-client-without-manually-convert-to-json) (where JAXB is also used).

Comment: im setting values to `setFileID` & `setDataHandlder` in client, how should the client be?

Comment: if you use JAXB (include the library in your project), in the client side you simply set the object and then pass it to the server (see the link I added in the end of my answer for details on how to set the client-side (using jersey-client) to communicate with the server sending a JSON message). On the server side you do the same to the received message. Do not forget to annotate your POJOs with the `@XmlRootElement`.

Comment: The setting of request message (filem) and response (fileresponse) looks fine... however you need to configure your client to talk with the server, for that follow the instructions in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335483/how-do-i-post-a-pojo-with-jersey-client-without-manually-convert-to-json?lq=1. Once you tried that and if you still have problems, update your original question with the complete details of the POJOs (which should be annotated with JAXB annotations) and the Jersey client and server side code. It will make it easier to help you.

Comment: created a new question with updated code. [NewQuestionHere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359399/sending-the-response-back-to-the-rest-webservice-from-client)

Comment: If this answered this specific question concerning "how to specify" the "custom object" consider to mark it as such. Concerning your new question, please report more details on "what is happening", what do you mean by "the server not taking the response of the client?", what error are you getting? - report this there, otherwise it is difficult to identify the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your REST endpoint indicates you want to consume and produce JSON. So the REST client needs to send JSON that can be deserialized into `FileModel`, and the `TransferInfomation` returned by `transferInfo` needs to be serialized into JSON to return to the client.

Typically, Java REST frameworks like [RESTEasy](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.4.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html), [Restlet](http://restlet.org/), [Camel](http://camel.apache.org/), and [Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) provide facilities that let you define a JSON serializer/deserializer like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and the mapping rules from JSON <--> Java, and the framework handles the details for you.

So if you use one of these frameworks, you will just have to configure them to use the preferred JSON tool and define the rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this like below:

Server Side:

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public String addRecord(CustomClass mCustomClass)
{
    ///
    ///
    ///
    return "Added successfully : "+CustomClass.getName();

}// addRecord
```

Client Side:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ///
    ///
    ///
    CustomClass mCustomClass = new CustomClass();
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    String strResult = client.target(REST_SERVICE_URL).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).put(Entity.xml(mCustomClass), String.class);
}
```