# JAX-RS send serialized Objects

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

As REST services intended to send xml or JSON type data,

```
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
```

and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354095/how-to-pass-a-custom-object-in-rest-webservice) Search Results 
    elaborates custom Object into JSON and then, tranffer it. Without doing so,

can any one let me know, Is there a way to send serialized objects straightforward ? Any resource, code snip where domestrate how JAX-RS send serialized Objects ?

Comment: What do you mean serialized? Do you mean like Java serialization protocol in binary format?

Comment: Did you even try to search? Have a look at http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Comment: @IwishIcouldthinkofagood. Since there were nothing found for what I search, I posted a question here. Thanks for your ref link. It is about object conversion into json. Here, I don't need to convert my objects into any json or xml. Send the serialzed objects straight forward ?

Comment: so you want to serialise your objects from one java app to another?

Comment: @IwishIcouldthinkofagood, Sorry, it is not clear for me "serialise your objects from one java app to another?" . One of my application has serialized objects to send to another application. The data type can be any but serialized.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo. Thanks for your attention. I m not clear what you mean by " Java serialization protocol " . I want to know can I use I/O Object streams to send serialized objects.

Comment: @Débora So you mean binary data, like a binary array containing your serialized objects?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo, Thanks. Yes and it can be a single serialized object also. Any array (collection) or single Objects.

Comment: @Débora One alternative is to send the binary data encoded in base 64 format within a json or xml body. And at the receiving side, unencode the base 64 back to a binary array and use it to deserialize the object.

Comment: There are two concepts here. One is serializing/deserializing an object and the other one is the client making a request and getting the data in the response. Where would you need further explanations?

Comment: @Débora ...however, one may wonder why can't you avoid the serialization and simply send the object in question in xml or json format???

Comment: @okiharaherbst. Thanks.  Here, the client need to make a request and as the response, the response is a serialized object.

Comment: @Débora Ok. Are both sides Java programms (or at least running on the JVM)? Are you in charge of coding both the client and the server sides?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo, because of my application concerns, conversion between, object and xml or json can be a performance hit and this process is very frequently happening. The other problem is, those objects which are supposed to send, are stored in the application (some time persistence POJO, cahed objected). Therefore, serialization is required.

Comment: @okiharaherbst, Thank your for your further support. Both applications are jee apps and my applications. I need to communicate among applications.

Comment: @Débora then why not just serialize your object using Java serialization and respond `application/octet-stream`? That's really as straightforward as it gets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this does work. I used the same way for an android application of mine. You can just use Object-Input/Output-Streams.

Unfortunately, i cannot provide any code atm, because I am at work, and the code is on my home pc ;)
I will update this post later on and provide you an example =)

So finally I found some time for this:

**This is the code on the server side. It receives a login String, and returns a boolean value and a String:**

```
@POST
@Path("/login/{id}")
@Consumes("application/xml")
public StreamingOutput login(@PathParam("id") int id, InputStream is) {
    String login[] = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        login = (String[]) ois.readObject();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.login[0] = login[0];
    this.login[1] = login[1];
    return new StreamingOutput() {
        public void write(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException,
                WebApplicationException {
            login(outputStream);
        }
    };
}
public void login(OutputStream os) {
    boolean result = false;
    connect();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = dbconn
                .prepareStatement("Select password from supervisor where username = '"
                        + login[0] + "'");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        String password = rs.getString("password");
        login[0] = password;
        if (login[1].equals(password)) {
            result = true;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        login[0] = e.toString();
    }
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
        oos.writeObject(result);
        oos.writeObject(login);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Now this is the code I wrote for my device:**

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    String[] login = { "xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx" };
    URL url = new URL(
            "http://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/login/1");
    try {
        // creates a HTTP connection
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        // httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        httpConn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        httpConn.connect();
        OutputStream outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
        oos.writeObject(login);
        outputStream.close();
        InputStream is = httpConn.getInputStream();
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
        try {
            boolean check = (boolean) ois.readObject();
            String[] logback = (String[]) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println(check + " " + logback[0] + " " + logback[1]);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println();
    } finally {
        if (oos != null) {
            oos.close();
        }
    }
```

Now this all looks kinda complicated, but this is taken out of a longer project context. I hope it still helps you to achieve what you want!

Sry again for being that late.

ZerO

Comment: Thanks Zero. If it support android, then it also should support, this jee application. Please let me have where you got the ref or any source when you are free. :)

Comment: Can you let me have the code snip or any source where demonstrates that object type data are tranfered between JAX-RS server app and the client. Thanks in advance.

Comment: omg, i'm sorry :/ I forgot about this one. i will be home late today, but i will update this post!

Comment: It s fine Zero.. I am waiting.. :) . But it d be more better if there is some thing on JEE spec :) .

Comment: Hi Zero, when you are free, just let me have working sample code please.

Comment: Thanks you so much Zero and I highly appreciate your support. I'd have to know few things. (1). What is the JAX-RS framework you used (RESTEasy or Jersey or..) ?   (2) The most important in your code part in your code is  ` return new StreamingOutput() {
        public void write(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException,
                WebApplicationException {
            login(outputStream);
        }
    };  and @Consumes("application/xml") `. and Please take a look at

Comment: 1) I used RESTEasy
2) I am not sure what your question is :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533280/resteasy-jax-rs-sending-custom-object-in-response-body. The paragraph "What if your content-type is not supported out of the box?" It says about a "implement a custom MessageBodyReader" . In this sample code, I think we don't need to have such a custom MessageBodyReader as it support Streams,right? Would you explain about "return new StreamingOutput() {)"

Comment: I don't know what to explain about "return new StreamingOutput()" :D

Comment: sorry. then let me know, what if we don't use "new StreamingOutput()", and just return the stream ?  . I am very beginning to REST, As I feel, new StreamingOutput() is REST's class/abstract or interface which supports us to return OutPutStream. It provides us  a Stream and write our object into it and  return as the result. is it correct? And other thing is what the framework you used? Jersey or RESTEasy ? :)

Comment: StreamingOutput is a simple callback interface that we can implement when we need to do raw streaming of response bodies. Thanks and again appreciate you Zero for all your support.

Answer (score 0):

Hey check out the java documentation here I think this may be what you are looking for? 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html