# Binding JSON to complex Java classes with Jersey

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jackson

My RESTful API I am developing with Jersey consumes and produces JSON, and I knew there was a dependecy where Jersey uses Jackson to automatically bind JSON to Java classes. I am a bit confused about the dependencies but using `jersey-media-json-jackson` seems to include this functionality.

I read this automatic binding is thought for POJOs, while my classes are much more complex than a simple POJO. So for POJOs the binding expects a default constructor, all setters (if you want to unmarshal) and all getters (if you're after marshalling). However, my classes are not like this. They have restrictions, there is no default constructor but a couple of specific ones, nor there are setters and getters for every member I want marshalled and/or unmarshalled.

Is there a workaround for this situation? Or should I just forget about using data binding? Maybe custom serializers can save the situation?

I just want this because I think it's much better to have this:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public GroceryItem createGroceryItem(GroceryItem item) {
    // process the item... do whatever
    return item;
}
```

than having a raw version:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String createGroceryItem(String jsonData) throws JsonProcessingException {
    return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(jsonData);
}
```

Or maybe I am just seeing this situation the wrong way. In that case, please enlighten me.

Comment: How does the non-raw version know about the POJO? Is there some preprocessing step that turns the JSON into the object? In other words, there is a raw version, you just don't want to maintain it

Comment: First question: there is no POJO. Second question: what I am trying to figure out if I should do that or what. Third sentence: I am not sure I understood that.

Comment: `GroceryItem` is not a POJO? For the third sentence, you say you want some automatic conversion from a String Request to a GroceryItem request, so in other words you do not want to "maintain", or write the JSON conversion step yourself and let Jersey+Jackson do it?

Comment: No, it is not a POJO. There is no `GroceryItem` class actually, I just used it as an example. The classes would actually be `Tournament`, `Schedule`, and similar.

Comment: And answering to the second part. Well, if I can avoid writing it myself and letting a library do it the happier I am. But since I am not dealing with POJOs it seems I would have to write my own custom serializers and deserializers. But at the same time I don't want to deal with raw data (`String`) in my service. I would want those methods to be receiving and returning the `Touranament` and such classes, instead of just strings.

Comment: This sounds very much like this question, or no?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335483/how-do-i-post-a-pojo-with-jersey-client-without-manually-convert-to-json

Comment: There is [`@JsonCreator`](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_457.html) for constructors, though you can only have it on one constructor. You can also [use builders](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBuilderPattern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No default constructor means you can't easily use Jackson to unmarshal.
No getters means you can't easily use Jackson to marshal.

You have several options:

1. Write your own JSON conversion code.
2. Change your class to produce POJO classes that are then used for JSON conversion.  Basically, add two methods to each class: createJsonData() and importFromJsonData() to marshal and unmarshal using Jackson.

**Edit**
toPOJO and fromPOJO might bee good method names.  Or, toJSON and fromJSON and use internal static POJO classes for Jackson serialization.

Comment: Maybe have two methods `fromJson` and `toJson` in the classes I want to serialize and deserialize? But that wouldn't get rid of having to deal with raw data in the web service.

Comment: Second question: so using Jackson is basically useless here? Or just the binding functionality it has? Because I can still use `JsonNode`, serializers, etc... from Jackson to write the mentioned methods right?

Comment: Jackson is not useless with classes that don't have getters and setters.  It is, however; not going to be seemless.  You will have to implement custom serialization.  You will need to spend time reading Jackson tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Please see my comment above